# Can I enter a purchased game code on a separate Xbox One and still have it registered to my profile?

Tags: xbox-one

If I purchase a digital download code for a game via Ex: Amazon but my console (Console A) isn't around, can I sign into my profile on another console in the house (Console B) at the moment and put in the code giving me the game to download on MY console (Console A) when it'ss around? Will the game still be mine or will it register as being owned by the owner of console B?

Answer (score 2):

Xbox codes are tied to the account, not the xbox.  If you are worried about it, just go to [this link to redeem your codes](https://account.microsoft.com/billing/redeem#/) - sign in, and redeem your code. Then you can download it to any xbox you are signed into.

Other accounts signed into the xbox marked as your ['home'](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/my-home-xbox) console can then use the game your purchased/redeemed without you signed in and other consoles can only play that game while you are signed in.